# Linear Algebra: Gram-Schmidt $A=QR$ factorisation and diagonal components of $R$

Tags: linear-algebra, gram-schmidt

With the $A=QR$ factorisation ($Q$ is a matrix with orthonormal columns $q_1$ to $q_n$, $A$ is a matrix with independent columns $a_1$ to $a_n$. $Q$ is created from the columns of $A$ with Gram-Schmidt), how would I prove that
$r_{jj}=\rVert A_j \lVert$, where $A_j$ is a column vector produced by Gram-Schmidt before it is divided by its length to produce $q_j$ of length 1?

Comment: Are you sure what you want to prove is true? $A=QR$ implies that $A_j=QR_j$. Hence $\|A_j\|=\|R_j\|$. This is in general greater than $|r_{jj}|$ unless $R$ is a diagonal matrix.

Comment: @user1551 I interpret the question with $A_j$ being the actual $j$th column of $A$ minus the projections onto $q_1,\dots,q_{j-1}$. It's not great notation, though.

Comment: I may have worded it a bit vaguely - $q_j=\frac{A_j}{\rVert A_j \lVert}$ - $A_j$ isn't a column of $A$. The $A_j$ here is supposed to be the vector from penultimate step in Gram-Schmidt - the step where you have found your orthogonal vector but haven't made it orthonormal yet.

Comment: @Ian Yes, that was what I meant - it is sloppy notation, I'll admit - but my linear algebra textbook - Gilbert Strang's 5th Edition - uses A, B, C instead, which I don't particularly think is much better

Answer (score 0):

Generally matrix multiplication $A=BC$ can be read as $a_1=Bc_1,a_2=Bc_2,\dots,a_n=Bc_n$, where $a_i$ are the columns of $A$ and $c_i$ are the columns of $C$. So in the case of $A=QR$ you have $a_i=Qr_i$.

Now what happens when you multiply out $Qr_i$? Only the first $i$ entries of $r_i$ are nonzero*. That means $a_i=\sum_{j=1}^i q_j r_{ji}$, thus $|r_{ii}|=\left \| a_i - \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} q_j r_{ji} \right \|$. This right hand side is what you called $\| A_i \|$, where $A_i$ is $a_i$ minus the projections of $a_i$ onto the $q_j$ with $j<i$.

Now to get the signs straight, you have to decide that the diagonal of $R$ consists of nonnegative numbers. This is not automatic from the assumption that $Q$ is orthogonal and $R$ is upper triangular, since you can always replace $q_j$ by $-q_j$ and then replace all of the $r_{ji}$ by $-r_{ji}$.

* It is possible that not even all $i$ of those are nonzero, but those are the ones that have any chance to be nonzero.

Comment: This seems correct, but I'll need some time to assimilate it first :D

Comment: Yep, works! Thanks for the proof man :D